# Assigning a local variable whose name is given as a string

Tags: ruby, local-variables

Within this itteration:

```
a1=[1,2,3,4,5]
a2=[1,2,3,4,5]
a1.each_with_index{|a, i| ... = a + a2[i]}
```

I want to assign to different local variables `b1`, `b2`, ..., `b5`, each per iteration to get:

```
b1 # => 2
b2 # => 4
b3 # => 6
b4 # => 8
b5 # => 10
```

I tried:

```
a1.each_with_index{|a, i| ('b' + i.to_s) = a + a2[i]}
```

but this doesn't work. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: This is most likely an XY-question.

Comment: I don't think you can create a local variable in the scope of the each_with_index method that will persist when this scope has ended.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [instance_variable_set](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set)

Comment: `instance_variable_set` sets an instance variable, not a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do (dynamically creating local variables) doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Why don't you just use an array.

```
a1=[1,2,3,4,5]
a2=[1,2,3,4,5]

a1.zip(a2).inject([]) { |b, (x1, x2)| b << x1 + x2 }

=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

You will achieve the same result. The item in position `b[0]` will be the sum of `a1[0] + a2[0]`.

There is no easy way to dynamically define a local variable exactly because it does not make a lot of sense. In fact, you will have hard time trying to use those variables anywhere because your code will depend on runtime generated variables.

In other words, how would you ever be able to use `b4`, if you don't even know if `b4` was ever generated. That's why an array is more convenient, you can know the size of the array and access all its items.

You can generate a local variable using `eval`, but as I said, it's definitely not the best approach.

Comment: thanks, like i said the example was simplified, so this solution isn't completely suitable. However, whether it's the right way to do it or not, I'm guessing that there isn't a way of doing what I'm looking for? I'm guessing it's not possible to use a string to define a variable name? I tried using eval but couldn't get it to work.. I can call a variable using eval but not define one...

Comment: Defining a variable in `eval` *does* work. It is defined inside of the binding of the eval invocation. It is not defined outside of it. That's just how local variables work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Binding#local_variable_set` to set *already existing* local variables. However, when you use it to set a *new* local variable (IOW to define one), the new local variable will be defined *inside* the `Binding` object but not the outside `Binding` you created it from.

The same thing happens with `eval`. Up to Ruby 1.8, `eval` leaked local variables to the outside scope, but that leak was plugged with Ruby 1.9.

In short, what you want is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `Binding` object.

```
a1=[1,2,3,4,5]
a2=[1,2,3,4,5]
b = binding()
a1.each_with_index{ |a, i| eval("b#{i + 1} = #{a + a2[i]}", b) }
(1..5).each do |i|
    eval("puts b#{i}", b)   
end
```

Now that the local variable is set you will be able to access it through that binding.

You can see an example [HERE](http://ideone.com/myY9m6)